# Java: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

### Error:

> Could not find or load main class CLASSNAME

### Command:

> java -cp "Path to MAIN class" "MAINCLASSNAME"

When I copy and paste the path, it is correct and when I go to the path and run the command it works fine.

So can anyone help me and tell me what is going on here and how to fix it?

```
java -cp /usr/home/dir1/2014Dir/Team1/Problem1/05:09:55/ Prob1
Error: Could not find or load main class Prob1
$

ls -l /usr/home/PCWSA/2014ConDir/Team1-14/Problem1/05:09:55/03-21-14_07.05.17:
total 4
-rw-r--r--  1 PCWSA  PCWSA  1359 Mar 21 07:05 Prob1.class
```

Comment: paste the path also here ...

Comment: Do you have a "manifest" file that is not in the "cp"?

Comment: java -cp  /usr/home/Dir1/2014Dir MAINCLASSNAME

Comment: Does MAINCLASSNAME have a package?

Comment: No it does not have a package

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: I guess it is important to tell you guys that I only take the java files and put them in my own directory. because I have an application that does the compiling and running.

Comment: Can you paste your console? This works just fine: https://gist.github.com/OscarRyz/9684454

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class Prob1

Comment: do this:  `ls -l /your/path Prob.class`

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 Dir1 Dir1 1359 Mar 21 07:09 Prob1.class

Comment: Ok, now can you paste all together? It looks like your Prob1.class is in your current directory and not in the directory you think it is. 
So, write the whole console ( not only the output )

Did you notice there is an space between the `/your/path` and `Probe1.class` ?

So, to stop guessing what your are doing and what the ouput is, paste the whole terminal output:
`ls -l /your/path/Prob1.class` 
`java -cp /your/path Prob1`

Comment: I am sorry, you mean the command and the output?

Comment: Yes, show us what are you actually doing, and not what you think you're doing

Comment: java -cp /usr/home/dir1/2014Dir/Team1/Problem1/05:09:55/ Prob1
Error: Could not find or load main class Prob1
$

Comment: :) Now... format it properly. Click on 'edit' in your original question, and paste both, the ls -l and the java command. Use 4 spaces to format or click the `{}` symbol in the toolbar to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Example to run the program ..

To compile the program go to src directory in command line and type the following

C:/blah/src > javac com\sample\MAINCLASSNAME.java

To run the program use the following command

C:/blah/src > java -cp . com.sample.MAINCLASSNAME

Use the command javac -d  to specify the place where u want to generate your class files .. Then run the java command from that directory.

Comment: But I am using a program to go and compile and run java applications, so that program takes the path as an argument.

Comment: Am i getting this right ?  . You are using a Runtime.exec or some process builder to compile and run other java programs ?

Comment: Exactly! that is what i am doing

Comment: +1 Also , perhaps you should read up on http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html .. It can give u some help in case u are making some mistakes while invoking.. Cos as OscarRyz said .. we cant see your computer

Comment: Well I'm sorry about the rage comment, but, it's very hard to help you if you don't tell us what are you doing. So, based on your last edit I added an answer, it looks like you're using different directories.

Comment: Thanks for your help. the problem still exist though! Anyway I will spend more time working on it to see why it exist.

Comment: ummm... did you read my answer? You have two very different directories there. Isn't that the problem?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it and the same thing happened. The issue was that the path contain "." in it and I think was causing the issue. I am making sure now!

Comment: @user2597012 Please use the following command javac -d "/usr/home/dir1/2014Dir/Team1/Problem1/05:09:55/" MainClassName.java  and then traverse to /usr/home/dir1/2014Dir/Team1/Problem1/05:09:55/ . Now run java -cp . <packageName>.MainclassName

Comment: Or probably it could be the path contains `:` which is a directory separator in unix

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last edit, it looks like you're trying find your .class file in the wrong directory

You're trying to execute it on:

```
/usr/home/dir1/2014Dir/Team1/Problem1/05:09:55/
```

But the file is on:

```
/usr/home/PCWSA/2014ConDir/Team1-14/Problem1/05:09:55/03-21-14_07.05.17:
```

So just use that directory instead:

```
java -cp "/usr/home/PCWSA/2014ConDir/Team1-14/Problem1/05:09:55/03-21-14_07.05.17:" Prob
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured what the problem was! My path to the MAINCLASS contained dots '.' and that was causing the issue, when I renamed the folders it worked fine. I hope this is going to be helpful.

Comment: Just to avoid you having the same problem later. Is is not the dots, but the colon.  This works properly `java -cp /some.path/ Blah` but this doesn't  `java -cp /some:path Blah`   You have to either use quotes or escape it: `java "/some/path" Blah" or `java /some\:path Blah`